# Custom component creation in intellij fails

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I just want to set custom list model for ComboBox. The commented code also didn't worked. I completely don't know why!

I'm working in Intellij Community Edition under JDK 1.8

```
import jssc.SerialPortList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class sampleForm extends JFrame {
    private JComboBox comboBox1;
    private JPanel panel1;

/*public sampleForm() {
    super("title");
    String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    comboBox1 = new JComboBox(portNames);
    add(comboBox1);
}*/

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("sampleForm");
    frame.setContentPane(new sampleForm().panel1);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void createUIComponents() {
    // TODO: place custom component creation code here
    String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
    comboBox1 = new JComboBox(port);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is already a `JFrame`, but you create another JFrame instance in the `main` method. So whatever you added in the `sampleForm` constructor has no affect visually because the `sampleForm` instance isn't the frame your showing. You're showing the new `JFrame` instance. So instead, do

```
public sampleForm() {
    super("title");
    String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
    comboBox1 = new JComboBox(portNames);
    panel1 = new JPanel(); // default FlowLayout
    panel.add(comboBox1);
    setContentPane(panel1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    sampleForm frame = new sampleForm("sampleForm");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Swing apps should be run on the Event Dispatch Thread.